# Why TX descriptor ring size should be 4 times that of RX descriptor ring size?

Tags: dma, descriptor, dpdk

I was reading Performance Optimization Guidelines for DPDK based applications and it is recommended that TX ring size should be 4 times that of RX ring size. I think Intel guys got this number empirically. Is there any reason to allocate the ring size in 1:4 ratio.

[image]

Here is the [link](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/dpdk-performance-optimization-guidelines-white-paper) for the performance guidelines:

Answer (score 0):

From https://communities.intel.com/community/tech/wired/blog/2011/06/24/parameter-talk-tx-and-rx-descriptors

> You can see the “Transmit buffers” are below it.  To modify the number of descriptors you just increase the value. In our Windows offerings there will be a limit of 2048 and it must be in increments of 8.  On the Transmit side the starting value is 512, but the same rules of 2048 by 8 still apply.  Why more TX than RX?  Our architecture favors the nondeterministic RX side for priority so there is more turnover of descriptors than the TX side.  Plus the O/S can sometimes not return TX assets back to the driver in a timely fashion.